# Does the foreach method create a copy of the array on which it is launched is JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I think in some cases it is, but not in others.

The following JS code does not produce an infinite loop, I deduce that foreach creates a copy of the array when called

```
var li = [""]
li.forEach(() => {
    li.push("");
});
```

But the following code return "1 2 3 AA 5". Which shouldn't be the case if he had created a copy of the array. So why?

```
var li2 = [1,2,3,4,5]
li2.forEach((el) => {
    li2[3] = "AA";
  console.log(el)
});
```

Ty

Comment: Have you considered the third option that `forEach` simply iterates from index `0` to index `array.length - 1`? That’s what the [specification](//tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.foreach) says.

Answer (score 1):

"Does the foreach method create a copy of the array on which it is launched is JS?"

No, it doesn't. It iterates over the initial range of the original array. If the range/size of the array changes while iterating, it doesn't influence the iteration of the `forEach`.

It's similar to

```js
function forEach(arr, cb) {
  for (let idx = 0, len = array.length; idx < len; ++idx) {
    cb(array[idx], idx, array);
  }
}

const array = [1, 2, 3];

forEach(array, (el, idx) => {
  array.push(el + idx);
});
console.log(array);
```

but the actual implementation also skips empty slots in sparse arrays.

Comment: Oh oki Thank you. I'v dont thinks to that